# Efficient access to global memory to pre-calculated locations

Tags: c++, caching, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am making an particle-based code in which every particle's neighbor lists are already generated with the initial condition and unchanged during the whole simulation, but the positions of each particle changes and therefore after some long time the 'neighbors' could be quite far away from each other. These neighbor lists correspond to the 'bond' to its initial positions, thereby unchanged.

I restrict the maximum number of neighbors as `MAX_NEIGHBOR` and with `N` particles there will be an array `Neighbors[N*MAX_NEIGHBOR]`. For the `i`'th particle, the index of its neighbors will correspond to `Neighbors[i*MAX_NEIGHBOR : (i+1)*MAX_NEIGHBOR]` (python range notation).

Say, to access a quantity (`Quantity[N]`) for each particles, basically this kind of approach could be considered.

```
int index = blockIdx.x;  // each block for one particle, and the threads will take care its neighbors
if (index > N) return;

int  neighborIndex = Neighbors[MAX_NEIGHBOR*index + threadIdx.x];  // coalesced
double  quantity = Quantity[neighborIndex];                        // cannot be coalesced
```

Evidently the access to `Quantity` is not coalesced. Since the `Neighbors[N*MAX_NEIGHBOR]` are constant during the simulations, I expect somehow I can do it better but how could this be technically done.

I can think of generating another array `NeighborsQuantity[N*MAX_NEIGHBORS]` so that I can access those in coalesced manner, but in generating this `NeighborsQuantity` will require reading non-coalesced memory in the another kernel.

There have been some comments with the texture memory in some documents, but going through CUDA programming guide it seems that the texture memory does not support `double3` type of variable.

The following is the kernel I am using.  Here I access `Pos`, and `Vol` of the neighbor particles. Also `Vel` is read, but it has no role so far. I have put it there just to prepare next implementations of more sophisticated models.

```
__global__ void calcBondAccelD(double4  *DVel_Dt,          // output
                               double4  *oldPos,           // inputs : oldPos[numParticles]
                               double4  *oldVel,           // oldVel[numParticles]
                               double   *Rho,              // Rho[numParticles]
                               double   *Vol,              // Vol[numParticles]
                               double   *BondStretch,      // BondStretch[numParticles*MAX_NEIGHBOR]
                               double   *Mu,               // Mu[numParticles*MAX_NEIGHBOR]
                               int      *Type,             // Type[numParticles]
                               int      *Neighbors,        // Neighbors[numParticles*MAX_NEIGHBOR]
                               int      *numNeighbors,     // numNeighbors[numParticles]
                               int       numParticles) {
  int sortedIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // one particle per thread

  if (sortedIndex >= numParticles) return;
  if ( (Type[sortedIndex] != 0) && (Type[sortedIndex] != 1) ) return;  // bonds only for main particles

  double3  pos = make_double3(oldPos[sortedIndex]);
  double3  vel = make_double3(oldVel[sortedIndex]);

  double3  force = make_double3(0.0);

  // examine neighbor list
  for (int i = 0; i<numNeighbors[sortedIndex]; i++) {
    int   neighborIndex = Neighbors[MAX_NEIGHBOR * sortedIndex + i];

    double3 pos2   = make_double3(oldPos[neighborIndex]);  // oldPos non-coalesced
    double3 relPos = pos2 - pos;
    double  dist   = length(relPos);

    double  _delta = params.horizon;
    double  _c     = 18.*params.modBulk / (CUDART_PI * _delta*_delta*_delta*_delta);

    force += _c * BondStretch[sortedIndex*MAX_NEIGHBOR + i] * Mu[sortedIndex*MAX_NEIGHBOR + i]
                * Vol[neighborIndex] * relPos / dist;      // Vol non-coalesced

  }

  // write new velocity back to original unsorted location
  DVel_Dt[sortedIndex] = make_double4(force / Rho[sortedIndex], 0.0);

}
```

I admit this is the most naive implementation that one can think of. While this kernel is practical enough on 3090 Ti for my current applications with 100,000~1,000,000 particles, I want it to be faster.

I am trying some variants of this using shared memory and so on, but the naivest one is still performing the best among my variants.

One of my variant is like this, I tried to plug the parallel reduction in it. While the memory access is still non-coalesced, there was a slight speed-up. But as I know 'fixed' neighbor lists, I thinks I had done it better in the memory access respect.

Any suggestions on improving this kernel?

```
__global__ void calcBondAccelD2(double4  *DVel_Dt,          // output
                                double4  *oldPos,           // intputs
                                double4  *oldVel,
                                double   *Rho,
                                double   *Vol,
                                double   *BondStretch,
                                double   *Mu,
                                int      *Type,
                                int      *Neighbors,
                                int      *numNeighbors,
                                int       numParticles) {
  int sortedIndex = blockIdx.x; // one particle per one block, threads taking care of its neighbors

  __shared__ double _s[256][6];

  if (sortedIndex >= numParticles) return;
  if ( (Type[sortedIndex] != 0) && (Type[sortedIndex] != 1) ) return;  // bonds only for main particles

  double3  pos = make_double3(oldPos[sortedIndex]);
  double3  vel = make_double3(oldVel[sortedIndex]);
  double   rho = Rho[sortedIndex];

  double3  force = make_double3(0.0);

  int     neighborIndex = Neighbors[MAX_NEIGHBOR * sortedIndex + threadIdx.x];
  int     _numNeighbor  = numNeighbors[sortedIndex];
  double3 pos2   = make_double3(oldPos[neighborIndex]);
  double  vol2   = Vol[neighborIndex];

  _s[threadIdx.x][0] = BondStretch[sortedIndex*256 + threadIdx.x];
  _s[threadIdx.x][1] = Mu         [sortedIndex*256 + threadIdx.x];
  _s[threadIdx.x][2] = 0.0;
  _s[threadIdx.x][3] = 0.0;
  _s[threadIdx.x][4] = 0.0;

  __syncthreads();

  if (threadIdx.x < _numNeighbor) {

    double3 relPos = pos2 - pos;
    double  dist   = length(relPos);

    double  _delta = params.horizon;
    double  _c     = 18.*params.modBulk / (CUDART_PI * _delta*_delta*_delta*_delta);

    force = _c * _s[threadIdx.x][0] * _s[threadIdx.x][1] * vol2 * relPos / dist;

    _s[threadIdx.x][2] = force.x;
    _s[threadIdx.x][3] = force.y;
    _s[threadIdx.x][4] = force.z;

  }
  __syncthreads();

  int threadIdx2;
  // parallel reduction - WARNING!! numThread should be fixed to 256 !!!
  if (threadIdx.x < 128) {
    threadIdx2 = threadIdx.x + 128;
    if (threadIdx2 < _numNeighbor) {
      _s[threadIdx.x][2] = _s[threadIdx.x][2] + _s[threadIdx2][2];
      _s[threadIdx.x][3] = _s[threadIdx.x][3] + _s[threadIdx2][3];
      _s[threadIdx.x][4] = _s[threadIdx.x][4] + _s[threadIdx2][4];
    }
   __syncthreads();
  }

  if (threadIdx.x < 64) {
    threadIdx2 = threadIdx.x + 64;
    if (threadIdx2 < _numNeighbor) {
      _s[threadIdx.x][2] = _s[threadIdx.x][2] + _s[threadIdx2][2];
      _s[threadIdx.x][3] = _s[threadIdx.x][3] + _s[threadIdx2][3];
      _s[threadIdx.x][4] = _s[threadIdx.x][4] + _s[threadIdx2][4];
    }
   __syncthreads();
  }

  if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
    threadIdx2 = threadIdx.x + 32;
    if (threadIdx2 < _numNeighbor) {
      _s[threadIdx.x][2] = _s[threadIdx.x][2] + _s[threadIdx2][2];
      _s[threadIdx.x][3] = _s[threadIdx.x][3] + _s[threadIdx2][3];
      _s[threadIdx.x][4] = _s[threadIdx.x][4] + _s[threadIdx2][4];
    }
   __syncthreads();
  }

  if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
    force.x = _s[0][2];
    force.y = _s[0][3];
    force.z = _s[0][4];

    // write new velocity back to original unsorted location
    DVel_Dt[sortedIndex] = make_double4(force / rho, 0.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253747/discussion-on-question-by-sangjun-lee-efficient-access-to-global-memory-to-pre-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.